# use theme colors while writing my template and blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, template, theme, page-layouts

Please take a look at the image below:

[image]

For the human eye its pretty clear that this site has a main theme color, which is the bluish color that the title, bars, and links share.

It's very rare to find a website that you can't define its main theme color(s).

Now here's my question: I'm writing an extension that add couple of blocks to the page (some divs, paragraphs, etc) and I want it to use the same color schemes as the general site. for example, a div with background the same as the toolbar, or the title.

How do I do it?

I looked at the css files Magento generated and I see for example that the top toolbar ("YOUR LANGUAGE") get its color from a class called "header-language-background", while the title get the color from a class called "logo", and the button get his color from the css for buttons in general...

So now that I want to use that color too, is there a proper way in Magento / css / something?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you just use the same CSS classes for your html elements that you find on a standard Magento page?

Comment: that's what I wanted to do but I searched for the colors I wanted and didn't find any decent class fitting. for example, for the bluish background color I could either use the button css, eg making my whole div a button (no bueno), or use the language toolbar, which I saw doesn't even appear on many magento websites. and besides, using these classes might cause weird artifacts with other themes, like themes adding "before" or "after" properties (tried it and second theme I used already did it)

Comment: if you searched the css files and didn't find anything fitting your needs then I suppose you have to add your own css file where you define what you need